# How to Add / Create Configurable Product and Attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product

How to add Configurable Product in magento 2.x

and add new Attribute in magento 2.x

Comment: you want to create it programatically or from back end ?

Comment: Is that Your Question ?

Comment: yes i create  Configurable Product in back end and also Attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find the below links and follow the steps

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-create-configurable-product-magento-2.html

https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/magento2/product-attributes